# How to solve no input in StreamTokenizer

Tags: java, stream, tokenize

I have the following lines of code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    StreamTokenizer t = new StreamTokenizer(inputStreamReader);
    while (t.nextToken() != StreamTolenizer.TT_EOF) {
        // process here
    }
}
```

So, when I run, I call : `java example.java < input.txt`

However, I can't handle the situation "no input file" when I call : `java example`.

It seems to run forever.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't redirect anything to stdin (System.in) such as "input.txt" in your example command line then your program will expect you to type data into the console window.

Perhaps you should refactor your program to expect a command line argument (e.g. by checking that "`args.length >= 1`") and interpret it as the name of the file to read.  If no file name is given then you can print an error message.  Additionally, you could interpret the special pseudo-filename "`-`" (a single hypen) to mean stdin so you can still redirect data.

For example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (args.length < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("no filename given");
  InputStream in = ("-".equals(args[0])) ? System.in : new FileInputStream(args[0]);
  InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
  StreamTokenizer t = new StreamTokenizer(inputStreamReader);   
  while(t.nextToken() != StreamTolenizer.TT_EOF) {
    // ...
```

However, don't forget to close the FileInputStream, e.g. in a `finally` block.